# NodeJS Websocket use variable in HTML (with express?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

I have been searching for two days now looking for a solution that might work for me. Sadly I have only seen examples and guides on how to setup a websocket server (that sends messages back and forth to clients) and a websocket client (that resides in browser). None of these really work for me, and I am not sure how to achieve what I want here.

Basically I have the following websocket:

```
require('dotenv').config()

const WebSocket = require('ws');

var connection = new WebSocket('ws://XXX');

connection.onopen = function () {
  connection.send(JSON.stringify({"authenticate":process.env.API}));
  connection.send(JSON.stringify({"XXX":"YYY"}));
  connection.send(JSON.stringify({
    "db" : "unique_id", 
    "query" : { 
        "table" : "users"
    } 
}));  
};
connection.onerror = function (error) {
  console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
};

connection.onmessage = function (e) {
  console.log('Server: ' + e.data);
  var myResponse = JSON.parse(e.data);
  var qList = myResponse.results;
};
```

What I want to do is have my nodeJS-script running, for example an express script with a html page, that also includes the response from onmessage. Why I am complicating this instead of just using the websocket client-side is that I cannot send my auth-code publicly.

Hope I have been clear enough, let me know if you are unsure of my question!

PS. If you think I would be better off using another websocket-script such as Socket.io - I have been looking at them and have not gotten much wiser sadly.

Comment: I have done a lot of work with WS server client implementation (made an automated bidding program), but I'm not sure where your program fails.  What's wrong with what you've done?

Comment: Is there a reason your database server only talks over websockets?

Comment: @gregnr He's using his server as a client to connect to a third party over web sockets.

Comment: Yeah I got that. Just found it strange that the third party communicates over web sockets.

Comment: I am unsure why they chose web sockets, sadly I have no way to change that though. ;)


My program (the socket connection) is working as intended @D.Walsh, my issue is that I have no idea how to pass on the messages received over to for example express. I think the main issue for me is that this is all done async, and I am no good at callbacks etc...

Comment: @ErikPersson gotcha!  I wasn't either and had to learn RxJS for my application.  But my application was all async.  I don't think you need to go that far.  When you say you want to pass it to Express, what do you want to do with it?  Send it as a response?  Store it?

Comment: Basically I want to run a rather small Express nodeJS-script where I include the response I get from onmessage in to a <table> on the generated HTML. On page refresh (or just a timed refresh of table element) I want the websocket to rerun so that my table stays up to date with what is in the database.

I know how to setup Express (sort of), I just can't seem to import the websocket onmessage in a manner that works as I want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of options.  Probably the easiest is to export the connection.  At the bottom of the file, e.g. `module.exports = connection`

Then in the express application, import the connection, e.g. `const connection = require('./path/connection');`

Then make a function that calls itself at a given interval and sends the appropriate message.

Then within the Express app you can use something like connection.on('message', (data, flags) => // do stuff);

Your other option is to create a store object.  E.g.

```
// ./store.js

class store  {
  constructor() {
    this.wsMaterial = {};
  }

 add(wsInfo) {
    this.wsMaterial[key] = wsInfo

 }

 get store() {
   return this.wsMaterial
 }
}

module.exports = new store()
```

Then import the store and updated it, e.g.

```
// ./websocket file

const store = require('./store');

...

connection.onmessage = function (e) {
  console.log('Server: ' + e.data);
  var myResponse = JSON.parse(e.data);
  var qList = myResponse.results;
  store.add(qList)
};
```

Then from Express...

```
// ./express.js

const store = require('./store');

store.get // all of your stuff;
```

Comment: @d-walsh, 
thank you so much for your detailed help! I think I am almost there now, the only thing I seem to have a hard time understanding is how to use `store.get` in my Express-script. I know how to pass other variables to my .ejs-file within render, but the store.get var is empty. 

Here is where I am at right now:

`app.get("/", function(req, res){

 const store = require('./store');

 var list = store.get;
 var test = "test";
 
 res.render('index', 
 { list: list,
 test: test
 });
});`

Comment: Crap I'm sorry. I was headed out the door and going way too quickly. In my example you want store.store not store.get. (And obviously you probably want to rename  the method. Store.store is a little odd :) )

Comment: No problem at all! Sadly I didn't catch that error myself... 
I think I am about done now, at least I am getting [object Object] shown, but I think there is an error with the store-file. When I try to run the websocket-js it says that `key`is not defined in the store.js file: `this.wsMaterial[key] = wsInfo
                    ^
ReferenceError: key is not defined`

Sorry for all the questions, a shame to give up on the finish line though!

Comment: I used an object and key as pseudo code. I didn't define key... it's up to you to decide how you want to do it. It sounds like a string may be all that you need.

Comment: I am terribly sorry that I am still unable to fully understand what I need to do here. I tried switching out KEY with my process.env.API as I assumed that was what could be needed, and lo and behold my websocket script worked yet again. I have no idea why though, and what is being sent when I run express is still just `[object Object]`. 

What am I supposed to add here? Might be that I am just tired now, or that I am way over my head.

Comment: Hi Erik, you'll really want to take a step back and become more proficient at Javascript.  I've been where you are, and I wish I had taken the time to level up earlier.  If you want suggestions on learning material let me know.  "[object Object]" is Javascript's string coercion of an object.  If you're console.log(ging), instead of console.log('Log: ' + log), do console.log('Log: ', log) and you'll get the object back.  Key is a object key.  E.g. var x = {} ; x['key'] = 1;  // x = { key: 1}  You'll want to do some reading on Javascript data structures.  It should all make more sense!

Comment: I have been reading up on data structures but I am sadly not understanding it just yet. I think the whole store.js-part is above my level somehow, so if you want I'd love some tips for reading material!

Ps. I understand that we are inserting something with key, I am just not sure what I am supposed to insert... 

Thanks!

Comment: Change it to this.. add(wsInfo) {
    this.wsMaterial[1] = wsInfo

 }

 get store() {
   return this.wsMaterial[1]
 }

Comment: Sigh, there is still something missing, been following the code from websocket.js to express.js and it seems as if it isn't being passed over when I run express.js. Thanks for your help though, really appreciate you took your time with this!